# Header with scrpage2 disappears on "last page" when using subfiles package

Tags: header-footer, scrpage2, subfiles

When I put two or more TeX files together with the [`subfiles`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package, the header disappears on the last pages of the included files.
Why is that?

The `Root.tex` file:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{subfiles}
 \usepackage{scrpage2}
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage{blindtext}

 \clearscrheadfoot
 \pagestyle{scrheadings}

 \begin{document}
   \subfile{test1.tex}\newpage
   \subfile{test2.tex}
 \end{document}
```

The used subfiles have the same content and are named `test1.tex` and `test2.tex`:

```
 \documentclass[Root.tex]{subfiles}
 \clearscrheadfoot
 \chead[Test]{Test}

 \begin{document}
   \Blindtext
   \Blindtext
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look, whether [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) could be a better choice instead of `subfiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After nobody answered here, I have asked Markus Kohm on komascript.de (in German: “[Kopfzeile verschwindet mit scrpage2 mit subfiles Paket](http://komascript.de/node/1765)”).

As I understood to keep it local, insert an `\clearpage` at the end of each subfile will solve the problem.

He also mentioned an global solution which is the following code (insert in root preamble):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\skip@preamble}{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\document\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\document\expandafter{\document}%
  }%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\enddocument\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\endinput
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\enddocument\expandafter{\enddocument}%
    \begingroup
    \edef\@currenvir{document}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][subfiles]{}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{\skip@preamble\input{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You should also mention the consequence of this ungrouping/globalization: Former local settings of subfiles will turn general.

Comment: And perhaps change to Community Wiki (edit answer, look at he end), because it’s Markus’ work?

Comment: Of course it's Markus' work. What is it about, the community wiki?

Comment: It’s a special post category, meant for easier collaborating, but with the effect, to one does not earn reputation from such posts, see [Privileges - edit community wiki](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).